# Iterate through object with "for" breaking mobile Safari/533.1

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

I feel like this is pretty straight forward.  Not sure why this is causing an issue in Mobile Safari.

```
var rowIndexArr = [];
var rowDatas = {"11480":{"tags":["Automotive"]}};
alert('still working'); // <-- works fine   
alert(rowDatas[11480].tags[0]) // <-- will alert "Automotive";

// what appears to be breaking the code
for(var index in rowDatas){
    rowIndexArr.push(index);
}


alert('still working?');  // <-- dead at this point.
```

Comment: Have you checked with weinre to see if errors are logged on the console?

Comment: @Pointy, I haven't.  I've just been using the "alert" to find out where the issue is.  I haven't used weinre yet.

Comment: Well weinre is a minor pain in the neck but once you get it set up it's way better than blindly groping in the dark :)